# Searching in Pre Order Traversal way

Tags: java, search, binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

I have a binary search tree. I know how to search using the search property. But my task is to search the tree without using search property.(Say, search in binary tree) This is how I have to search.

**1**. If you find the value in the current node return it.

**2**. else search in right. If not found in right, then search in left

**3**. If not found in the whole tree return null.

**This is what i tried.**

```
public Node search(int val)
{
    Node target = this;
    if(target.getVal() == val)
        return this;
    else if(target.getRight() == null && target.getLeft() == null)
        return null;
    if(target.getRight() != null)
    {
        return target.getRight().search(id);
    }
    if(target.getLeft() != null)
    {
        return target.getLeft().search(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Problem with my code is, if right child exists and val is not found in right I'm getting `null` value. (Not searching in left). How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Node search(int val)
{
    Node target = this;
    if(target.getVal() == val)
        return this;
    else if(target.getRight() == null && target.getLeft() == null)
        return null;
    if(target.getRight() != null)
    {
        return target.getRight().search(id); //here lies the problem
    }
    if(target.getLeft() != null)
    {
        return target.getLeft().search(id);
   }
return null;
```

}

The problem in your code is that you are returning the result of search in right subtree of the node being searched.

Here's the updated code

```
public Node search(int val)
{
    Node target = null;
    if(this.getVal() == val)
    {
        return this;
    }
    else if(this.getRight() == null && this.getLeft() == null)
        return target;
    if(this.getRight() != null)
    {
        target = this.getRight().search(id);
    }
    if(target==null && this.getLeft() != null)
    {
        target = this.getLeft().search(id);
   }
   return target;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but I'd change your logic a bit:

```
public Node search(int val)
{
    if(this.getVal() == val)
        return this;

    if (this.getRight() != null) {
        Node right = this.getRight().search(id);
        if (right != null)
            return right;
    }

    if (this.getLeft() != null) {
        Node left = this.getLeft().search(id);
        if (left != null)
            return left;
    }

    return null;
}
```

In your version you are returning a solution with the sole requirement that the node on the right or left is not null. You have to return a solution only if a solution is found.